# Wordpress (Understrap framework) custom JS not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress custom theme using the child-theme of Understrap.

I'm adding my custom jQuery to **child-theme > src > js > custom-javascript.js**, and the file is already commented with "*// Add your custom JS here.*"
https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child/blob/main/src/js/custom-javascript.js

I did this as instructed from the Understrap Documentation:

> "Add your own JS to /src/js/custom-javascript.js to have them bundled into /js/child-theme.js."
> https://docs.understrap.com/#/understrap-child/npm

I've run the script in the console, and it works as intended, so the error is not with my script.

Yes, I have tried clearing my cache.

I've seen a few other questions related to needing to update a gulpfile.js, but no such file is included in my child OR parent theme, I have used the search function, and I also cannot find it on the Understrap GitHub repo.

Is the script not enqueuing properly? Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT: RESOLVED
Was unable to find the source of the error. Ended up doing a fresh install of the Understrap child theme, and migrating my custom files over. This eventually resolved my problem and the JavaScript started working again.***

Comment: Was unable to find the source of the error. Ended up doing a fresh install of the Understrap child theme, and migrating my custom files over. This eventually resolved my problem and the JavaScript started working again.

Comment: I'm not able to see result of editing `$primary` color in `_theme_variables.scss` in my understrap-child theme, where am I going wrong ?
[Full question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825027/understrap-child-theme-edit-not-visible-sass-color-variable-not-applied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by doing a fresh install of the Understrap child theme and migrating my already written custom files over.

Comment: Having the same issue, have used Understrap in the past and this was never an issue...

Answer (score 0):

I added `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` to wp-config so that the `theme.js` file was loaded instead of `theme.min.js`. This then allowed any of my custom javascript to load. However, when minification is on, the .min.js files don't get recompiled. I am submitting an issue on Understrap github.